# C - Long double min and max value

Tags: c, macros, double, max, long-double

Is correct that min and max value of a long double are like double ones? They use 8 byte each other and max arrive at about E308 (10^308). Long double should use 16byte and arrive at >E4000, shouldn't it? Or it depends from the computer? I check these values using macro LDBL_MAX and sizeof keyword (for byte occupation).
Is it normal or I committed some errors (like in the format specifier - I use %Le to print)?
Ah, I used Visual Studio 2015 to compile and execute.
Thank you!

Comment: long double only needs to be as long as a double... so there may be no difference, depends on your compiler, abi, arch, etc

Comment: @GradyPlayer ah ok, thanks for the info! :)